# android c++ use localtime signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x86668f9

Tags: android, c++, time

andorid 10：In one of my custom services ，when i use

```
    time_t curr;
    struct tm *tTM = NULL;
    char pcurDate[24] = {0};

    time(&curr);
    LOG_I("[getClearAttackStamp][%d]:curr = %ld.\r\n",__LINE__,curr);
    tTM = localtime(&curr);
    LOG_I("[%s][%d]: %4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.\r\n",__func__,__LINE__, tTM->tm_year+1900,tTM->tm_mon+1, tTM->tm_mday,tTM->tm_hour,tTM->tm_min,tTM->tm_sec);
```

localtime(&curr) crash：

```
I app: [getClearAttackStamp][188]:curr = 1705985618.
F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x86668f9 in tid 8695 (testserver), pid 8695 (testserver)
I crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
I /system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 8695
I crash_dump32: performing dump of process 8695 (target tid = 8695)
F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: /QKQ1.200407.002/eng.builde.20240117.171303:userdebug/test-keys'
F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2024-01-23 12:53:38+0800
F DEBUG   : pid: 8695, tid: 8695, name: lifecycleserver  >>> /product/bin/testserver<<<
F DEBUG   : uid: 1000
F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x86668f9
F DEBUG   :     r0  b0e2826b  r1  086668f9  r2  b0ec81a0  r3  b0e2826d
F DEBUG   :     r4  b0ec8208  r5  bec4f16c  r6  b0ec6a74  r7  bec4f1a8
F DEBUG   :     r8  bec4f170  r9  b0ec8260  r10 00000000  r11 8103145b
F DEBUG   :     ip  00000002  sp  bec4f0a8  lr  bec5168c  pc  b0ea76f0
F DEBUG   : 
F DEBUG   : backtrace:
F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 0009b6f0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (getenv+48) 
F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 000a23ff  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (tzset_unlocked+18) 
F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 0009e2fd  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (localtime+28) (BuildId: )
F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 00007153  /product/bin/testserver
F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 00006f8b  /product/bin/testserver
F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 00006075  /product/bin/testserver
```

Does it seem like a problem with the time zone environment? tzset_unlocked ...
But this seems to be standard usage, so I don't understand why the error occurred

android 10 :This problem during the first burn img
After reboot device, this code go to normally

Comment: Why did you tag this as C++? Use of `NULL` rather than `nullptr`, use of `time()` and `localtime()` rather than using what's available in the `chrono` header? Are you sure you are not writing C compiled with a C++ compiler? And is `LOG_I` a macro? Eeew. Why not a proper function?

Comment: Try using sanitizers.

Comment: This looks liek "C" not "C++", You do know C++ has `std::chrono` for anything related to time do you?

Comment: Check `tTM` value for `NULL` before dereferencing.